# How can I mock an auto closeable resource properly?

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test for this:

```
try (final DatagramChannel channel = helper.createChannel()) {

...

}
```

In my test, I mock the helper (using Mockito), and tell helper.createChannel() to return a mocked channel.

This test fails with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:111)
```

I understand that the try-with-resources facility in Java calls the close() method in the DatagramChannel upon exiting the try block, but shouldn't the close() method in the mocked DatagramChannel be called upon?

The debugger tells me that the closeLock in AbstractInterruptibleChannel is null.

Should I subclass the DatagramChannel, override the close() method in it, and then mock my subclass instead?
Or, am I doing something wrong in a more profound way (the helper mock returns a mock)?

Regards,
Fredrik Israelsson

Test code, upon request:

```
@Mock
private InetAddress peerAddress;
@Mock
private UDPChannelHelper helper;
@Mock
private DatagramChannel channel;

private UDPTransportImpl transport;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(helper.createChannel()).thenReturn(channel);
    transport = new UDPTransportImpl(peerAddress, 0, helper);
}

@Test
public void testNormalSubmit() throws Exception {
    transport.submit("Hello");
}
```

As you can see, I do not specify any behavior for channel.close(). I am under the belief that I should not have to, because close() returns void.

Comment: Can you show your code where you are mocking these? Also have you debugged through and confirmed that a)helper is actually a mock, b) helper.createChannel() also returns a mocked object?

Comment: Added the test code, and yes, in the debugger, both helper and channel are of the type BlaBlaBla$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB.

Comment: This page: http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing%28%29 explicitly states "that void methods on mocks do nothing by default! ". So we can only assume that the finally block isn't executing on a mock. Your code looks fine to me though so Im not sure why that is..you certainly shouldn't need to subclass it yourself though.

Comment: One thing to try, put a break point inside the try block. Then in Eclipse go to Debug view, firstly triple check that channel is a mock, then goto expressions. Enter channel.close() and execute it and see what the result of this is .

Answer (score 9):

You are mocking a real class `DatagramChannel`, that extends `AbstractInterruptibleChannel`. However the `AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close` is final, and Mockito cannot currently mock final code. Which explains why you have an NPE in the code.

I must remind you that it is commonly accepted that mocking types you don't own is bad practice. I've seen people do it and they had bad surprises years later when the real implementation had changed, but the mock behavior didn't, so they wrongly thought everything was alright when they updated the version of the libraries.

Still if you want to continue this way because you have valid reasons for that (and there are some), you could return instead a mock of an interface, like `Channel` that actually extends `Closeable`. Or you can use any other interface that you need to interact with that were present in `DatagramChannel`. Also if you need more than one interface just use `mock(Channel.class, withSetting().extraInterfaces(...))`.

Hope that helps
Cheers,
Brice

Comment: If mocking types you do not own is a bad practice, then getting 100% coverage with unit tests is usually impossible without the bad practice... (I assume unit tests have to be isolated from any external stuff)

Comment: @TomaszPosłuszny In my experience achieving 100% coverage with unit test is reaching too high for other reasons than good design. However I believe acceptance/integration test can nicely complement those to cover most of the remaining percentage. Nevertheless this answer has been written in 2013 with mockito 1.x without final mocking, now with v3.x mocking those final types/methods should be possible.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and using spy(..) instead of mock(..) has worked for me. I was trying to simulate an error while truncating a file and my system was handling the error accordingly.

```
FileChannel fileChannel = spy(FileChannel.class);
mockStatic(FileChannel.class);
when(FileChannel.open(eq(filePath), eq(StandardOpenOption.WRITE))).thenReturn(fileChannel);
when(fileChannel.truncate(1000L)).thenThrow(new IOException("Unable to truncate file"));

...

// Snippet being tested!
fileChannel = FileChannel.open(filePath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
fileChannel.truncate(1000L); // Will throw the exception!
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution, using spy(...) instead of mock(...) solved this null reference issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Keeping aside whether you should be doing this or not, one way you can work around this issue is by "fixing" the AbstractInterruptibleChannel mock instance (whether a FileChannel, a DatagramChannel, etc.) by providing an Object for the `closeLock` field used to synchronize the close call.

```
private static void fixChannelMock(AbstractInterruptibleChannel mockFileChannel) throws Exception {
    Field closeLockField = AbstractInterruptibleChannel.class.getDeclaredField("closeLock");
    closeLockField.setAccessible(true);
    closeLockField.set(mockFileChannel, new Object());
}
```

Be prepared to have to fix the above code on minor Java releases though as the internal implementation of AbstractInterruptibleChannel might change.